# (Pandas) How to find what bin events fall in, where bins are defined by separate dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have one Pandas dataframe `bins` with checkpoints that split a number line into bins. The index is the name of that bin and the value in `'st'` is the starting point of the bin eg:

```
     st
0:   0
1:   4
2:   6
3:   11
4:   17
```

Thus bin 2 is the space from 6 to 11

I then have another dataframe `events` with events that have a location in the number line, eg:

```
     loc
0:   1
1:   3
2:   6
3:   8
4:   10
5:   11
6:   14
7:   18
8:   20
```

I would like to find for each event in `events`, what bin it falls in, and what is the difference to the beginning to the bin, eg:

```
     loc   seg  diff
0:   1     0    1
1:   3     0    3
2:   6     2    0
3:   8     2    2
4:   10    2    4
5:   11    3    0
6:   14    3    3
7:   18    4    1
8:   20    4    3
```

I was able to make it work using a for-loop, somewhat optimized by the fact that both dataframes are sorted, but I wanted to know if there is a good way to solve this without loops.

In reality, my dataframe `bins` is 100's of rows and `events` is 10000's, and the values in `st` and `loc` are datetime objects, so I would like to find `diff` as timedeltas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `st` column is sorted, you can use [numpy.searchsorted()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) to find indices where elements should be inserted to maintain order.

```py
import numpy as np

events['seg'] = np.searchsorted(bins['st'], events['loc'])-1
```

```
   loc  seg
0    1    0
1    3    0
2    6    1
3    8    2
4   10    2
5   11    2
6   14    3
7   18    4
8   20    4
```

Then map the newly created indices column to `st` Series to get corresponding value

```py
events['diff'] = events['loc'] - events['seg'].map(bins['st'])
```

```
   loc  seg  diff
0    1    0     1
1    3    0     3
2    6    1     2
3    8    2     2
4   10    2     4
5   11    2     5
6   14    3     3
7   18    4     1
8   20    4     3
```

Comment: I like seeing `searchsorted` (-:

Answer (score 2):

In your case do with `pd.cut`

```
events['seg'] = pd.cut(events['loc'],st['st'].tolist()+[np.inf],labels=st.index,right=False)
events['diff'] = events['loc'] - events['seg'].map(st['st']).astype(int)

events
Out[31]: 
   loc seg  diff
0    1   0     1
1    3   0     3
2    6   2     0
3    8   2     2
4   10   2     4
5   11   3     0
6   14   3     3
7   18   4     1
8   20   4     3
```

Comment: o/ Great answer (-: